# In Google Sheets, make a clickable hyperlink from an image using a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have my own image set on my Google Sheet. Then I can add a script to it. I tried something like this that works for Docs but it does not work for Sheets :

```
function insertLink() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, "link 
text").setLinkUrl("stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Comment: I tried the following but editAsText is not found in the object Sheet : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().editAsText().insertText(0, "link text").setLinkUrl("www.google.com");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution using a formula in a cell :

```
=HYPERLINK( "http://www.google.com" ; IMAGE("https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/sergio-ramos-of-real-madrid-is-seen-during-the-uefa-champions-league-picture-id962895784" ) )
```

But it does not work for me as I can't use a cell to write the formula. Indeed I want to click on a image that is above a background image. Therefore if I write the formula, the image will be hidden behind my background image.